# python django - csv file not getting downloaded in IE 8

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to download a CSV file like this:

```
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/force-download'
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'public'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="results.csv"'
    writer = UnicodeWriter(response, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, encoding="utf-8")
```

It works in FF, Chrome, IE>=9 but not IE<=8

Does anyone know what the difference is?

Comment: What if you try `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/force-download`? `application/force-download` is not a standard content-type and you'll have problems with browser support.

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232103/how-do-i-get-csv-file-to-download-on-ie-works-on-firefox

Comment: Also, this forum thread also talks about the issue: http://www.htmlforums.com/php-programming/t-force-download-in-ie8-is-it-impossible-117254.html

Comment: i already tried all that

Comment: @user2424160 Please include all the attempts you made. It would be sad if more suggestions come in you've already tried. Also please **edit** your question to include all these details. Comments aren't really fit for this on a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
csv_name = urllib.urlencode({'filename':'"results.csv"'})  #this is if you really really want the double quotes, otherwise just use cvs_name = 'results.csv'

response = HttpResponse(csv_content, mimetype='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; ' + csv_name + '.csv'
response['Content-Type']        = 'text/csv; charset=utf-8';

return response
```

Also, the urlencode is useful in case you have spaces, pluses, minuses in the file name. Otherwise IE will not work.