# PHP: IE11 Open formatted .csv file in Excel

Tags: php, csv, internet-explorer-11

So I have problems opening .csv file which is downloaded with IE11 and If I use chrome or mozilla etc. file is formatted well.

Case: In php I am generating list and export as .csv. If I download that file with ex. Chrome and open in Excel, each column is formatted well, but same process in IE11 and output is unformatted text.

Below you can find code, and outputs:

Here is the php code
[image]

Here is .csv file (downloaded using chrome, mozilla, opera, safari)
[image]

And here is output from IE11

[image]

Does anybody have idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: To do that you have to import data into excel via wizard and choose column separator semicolon instead of comma

Comment: See this question - may be related and help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232103/how-do-i-get-csv-file-to-download-on-ie-works-on-firefox

Comment: @AlexSlipknot but why it works in Chrome and other browser with normal openning? I know that I can do this but its hard to explain to customers this process. There is also option to change settings in Control Panel but it must be another solution (add something to header etc.)

Comment: Code;Place;Country **,** Price ? Looks like you've got semi-colons as column separators everywhere except between Country and Price - unless the WebKit/Firefox browsers are magically fixing that somehow I don't think it should work quite right as-is anyway.

Comment: can i share code what i am having in php which is working fine in IE11 too .. but its little bit different from yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2232167/635522) to a similar problem.

> Try using those headers:
>
> ```
>   header("Pragma: public");
>   header("Expires: 0");
>   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
>   header("Cache-Control: private",false);
>   header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
>   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"exportevent.csv\";" );
>   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
> ```
>
> I think that the octet-stream content type forces IE to download the
>   file.

Answer (score 0):

This code is what working fine for me

```
 // fetching data from database 
 $products = Product::undeletedProducts();
 // heading in array
 $columns = array('Code','Place','Country','Price');
 header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filenameproduct_list_'.time().'.csv');
    // file creation with write mode
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    // putting headings in csv file
    fputcsv($output, $columns);
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        $outRow = [];
        // for dynamic columns
        foreach($columns as $column)
        {
          array_push($outRow,$user->{$column});
        }
        fputcsv($output, $outRow);
    }
```

Comment: this is perfectly working for me.. let me know whether it works for you or not

Comment: Actually another part of my code create dynamically columns and values and it works good, only problem was with downloading and opening file using IE11. But however, thank you for your time!

Comment: you can test it sir, I will be glad if this is helpful to you... and welcome sir